# Rolling down a data group over the time using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

Hello I'm trying to merge/roll two dataframes.
I would like to merge the 'dfDates' and 'dfProducts' then roll the products on 'dfProducts' group/members until the date that a new group/members is available.
I tried to use a outer join between both dataframes but I dont know how to roll the groups...

Follow below how the dataframes looks like and how I would like the 'dfFinal'

```
dfProducts

   Date      Product

2018-01-01      A  
2018-01-01      B 
2018-01-01      C 
2018-01-03      D
2018-01-03      E
2018-01-03      F

dfDates

   Date        

2018-01-01       
2018-01-02   
2018-01-03       
2018-01-04      

dfFinal

   Date      Product

2018-01-01      A  
2018-01-01      B 
2018-01-01      C 
2018-01-02      A  
2018-01-02      B 
2018-01-02      C 
2018-01-03      D
2018-01-03      E
2018-01-03      F
2018-01-04      D
2018-01-04      E
2018-01-04      F
```

Answer (score 2):

The easiest option I can see is to group everything by date first, then reindex to your desired range to drop `nan`s into the empty spots, then ffill those:

```
(
    df
    .groupby("Date")
    ['Product']
    .apply(list)
    .reindex(pd.date_range(start=dfDates['Date'].min(), end=dfDates['Date'].max(), freq='D'))
    .fillna(method='ffill')
    .explode()
)

2018-01-01    A
2018-01-01    B
2018-01-01    C
2018-01-02    A
2018-01-02    B
2018-01-02    C
2018-01-03    D
2018-01-03    E
2018-01-03    F
2018-01-04    D
2018-01-04    E
2018-01-04    F
Name: Product, dtype: object
```

Comment: would be more general if you would do `start=df['Date'].min()` and `end=df['Date'].max()`, besides that good answer +1

Comment: Good suggestion - I'll modify.

Comment: I tried this method but the code isnt working and return to me the following error:

AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'explode'

Comment: I found the error related to the ‘explode’. My pandas wasnt in the current version then the 'explode' isn't available. I updated the lib and now everything is working :) Other quick question: if my 'dfProducts' have other columns (ie.'ProductPrice', 'ProductDetail'...) how can I explode this data frame?

Answer (score 0):

Define the following function:

```
def getLastDateRows(dat, df):
    rows = df.query('Date == @dat')
    n = rows.index.size
    if n == 0:
        lastDat = df.Date[df.Date < dat].iloc[-1]
        rows = df.query('Date == @lastDat')
    return pd.DataFrame({ 'Date': dat, 'Product': rows.Product })
```

Then *apply* it to each *dfDates.Date* and *concat* the results:

```
pd.concat(dfDates.Date.apply(getLastDateRows, df=dfProducts)\
    .tolist(), ignore_index=True)
```

The result is just as expected.

## Appendix

The solution proposed by *Randy* can be a bit improved:

```
dfProducts.groupby('Date').Product.apply(list)\
    .reindex(dfDates.Date).ffill().explode().reset_index()
```

Differences:

- Reindex is on *dfDates.Date* (not the whole range), so the result will
  contain **only** dates present in *dfDates*, which can contain
  intentional "gaps", e.g. for weekends.
- The final call to *reset_index* causes that the result is a *DataFrame*
  (not a *Series*).